# adding a string to an arraylist<String>

Tags: java, arraylist

i am having a trouble adding a string into an ArrayList. my goal is to create a list of an array using a for loop. however each time it is looping it seem always erase the previous data and then it replace it with the new data, so the ArrayList only have the value of 1 instead of 4. here is the full code

```
public class SerialDemo {

    private static File f;
    private static Save obj1;
    private static Save obj;

    private static int number = 4;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            //getData("newFile.txt");
            for(int i = 0; i < number;i++) {
                obj = new Save();
                obj.arrayLocationX.add(String.valueOf(10 * i));
                obj.arrayLocationY.add(String.valueOf(20 * i));
                obj.arrayTitle.add(String.valueOf(30 * i));
                obj.arrayDescription.add(String.valueOf(40 * i));
                obj.arrayNumber.add(""+i);
            }

            for(String x:obj.arrayLocationX) {
                System.out.println(obj.arrayLocationX);
            }

            //setData("newFile.txt");
            /*getData("newFile.txt");

            for(int i = 0; i < obj.arrayLocationX.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Value of Desc"+obj1.arrayNumber);   
                System.out.println("Value of locX"+obj1.arrayLocationX.get(i)); 
                System.out.println("Value of locY"+obj1.arrayLocationY.get(i)); 
                System.out.println("Value of Tit"+obj1.arrayTitle.get(i));  
                System.out.println("Value of Desc"+obj1.arrayDescription.get(i));   
                System.out.println("  ");
                System.out.println(obj.arrayDescription.size());
            }*/
        }catch(Exception e) {

        }

    }

    private static void setData(String fileName) {
        // set the object or data
        try {
            f = new File(fileName);
            FileOutputStream fps;
            fps = new FileOutputStream(f);
            ObjectOutputStream dos = new ObjectOutputStream(fps);
            dos.writeObject(obj);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e) {

        }
    }
    private static void getData(String fileName) {
        // get the object or data
        try {
            f = new File(fileName);
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
            ObjectInputStream Oin = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
            obj1 = (Save) Oin.readObject();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

        }catch(IOException e) {

        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {

        }
    }

}

class Save implements Serializable {
    ArrayList<String> arrayNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayLocationX = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayLocationY = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayDescription = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Comment: try removing empty catch clauses, see if there any exception

Comment: i have delete the try{}catch{} but the result stay the same. it give me 1

Comment: try moving `obj = new Save();` before the loop

Comment: moving the obj = new Save(); did it. thank you bro

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new `obj` is created in every iteration hence your added string is lost. Try moving `obj = new Save();` before the loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i = 0; i < number;i++) {
            obj = new Save();
```

`obj` is instantiated as a new `Save` every time the loop begins again. This means all your progress from the previous loop is lost and the new `Save` is the one that receives the inserts. You only want to create `obj` once, somewhere before the loop. Swapping the order of the lines should cause the program to work.

```
obj = new Save();
for(int i = 0; i < number;i++) {
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation dude, i understand it better now.